# What API Key is Google using when I load the JS script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I am loading the google maps/places JS API in my web app like this in my web/Ionic mobile app.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

I am not providing an API key in that URL. What api key is google using? If different users use the web-app, will it use a seperate API key for each user? and therefore each user will have a limit on the requests as opposed to the entire app having the limit?

This is the angular directive using the API. It doesn't have a key defined in it.

https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What api key is google using? If different users use the web-app, will it use a seperate API key for each user?

No, Google API is not requires key. But key gives very useful information (read the link below). Key is unique for each app you use (if you register it in console). More detailed information can be found at Google Developer Console and at page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

> And therefore each user will have a limit on the requests as opposed to the entire app having the limit?

About limits in Maps Google wrote here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Comment: I have seen this pages but that does not answer my question of how would google know the traffic was coming from my app?  App will be running on each users phone and requests are made by the client.